# Disable “Allow USB debugging?” message

Tags: usb-debugging

I have a tablet with a cracked screen, but I can use it with usb mouse connected via OTG. One problem is that I cannot connect it in debug mode because whenever I connect my tablet to PC, the message "Allow USB debugging?" appears. So it's a problem: while tablet connected to PC message appears, but in order to accept it I need my mouse connected, but USB port is busy. I have no root, but I have recovery. So is there a way to deal with this message? I know that I can use bluetooth mouse, but I wont have it as soon as I want to debug my apps.

Comment: Did you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895208/how-to-disable-authorization-pop-up-on-android ?

Comment: may be Im doing something wrong, but looks like my adb (1.0.32) does not recognize command adb disable-verity

Comment: What about ADB over air (tcpip) ? Learn more about it on [Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#wireless)

Comment: you have to connect your device via usb first to make adb listen on port 5555 by tcpip